# API 'BaseVariant.getApplicationIdTextResource' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'VariantProperties.applicationId'

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

When building gradle I'm getting this message:

> `API 'BaseVariant.getApplicationIdTextResource' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'VariantProperties.applicationId'`

I'm using `Android Studio 4.1 Canary 10` and `gradle:4.1.0-alpha10`

Comment: happened for me but for 'RecyclerView'

Answer (score 134, accepted):

It seems like the [Navigation Safe Args plugin](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data#Safe-args) uses `getApplicationIdTextResource()`, so it is most likely that the error message is caused by your usage of that plugin.

You'd want to star the [existing issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/159542337) to ask the Safe Args plugin to use the new replacement API.

Comment: UPDATE: According to [this comment](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/159542337#comment37), it's been fixed in Android Studio 4.2 Beta 2.

Comment: and if you're using arctic fox, you're still doomed :|

Comment: 2.4.0-alpha02 fixed the issue, works on arctic fox too  (latest: alpha06)

Comment: Latest alpha 2.4.x-alphaXX seems to fix with artic fox as @norbDEV mentioned.

Comment: over a year for google to fix this things

Comment: Still getting this issue on Bumblebee, and azure pipelines. safeargs version `2.3.1`

Comment: I just upgraded to latest version and no warning or error came in this respect.

Answer (score 37):

Changing to androidx.navigation:navigation-*:2.4.0-alpha02 as described [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation#2.4.0-alpha02) allowed a build of my app under Arctic Fox without getting the getApplicationIdTestResource warning

From the application build.gradle file:

```
def nav_version = "2.4.0-alpha02"
classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$nav_version"
```

And in the build.gradle file:

```
def nav_version = "2.4.0-alpha02"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:$nav_version"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:$nav_version"
androidTestImplementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-testing:$nav_version"
```

Comment: This is the best answer, as it is the most up to date. Should be closer to the top.  Correct answer should be a combination of this and the current correct answer.

Answer (score 9):

few days i see the same issue. Then i go to ->
**build.gradle** file

[My Dependencies before update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNVAc.jpg)

check the **dependencies**

I update the dependencies google services to 4.3.4

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

[After update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWR93.jpg)

Now its working fine.

Comment: FYI: 4.3.4 comes with other issues like https://github.com/google/play-services-plugins/issues/163

Comment: I upgraded to the latest version of ```google-services```.

Answer (score 6):

This error was for `NavigationComponent` for me in Android Studio Cannery 13.

So I changed the nav_version to this and My issue was solved.

```
 ext {
    ***************    nav_version = "2.4.0-alpha10" ************
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0-alpha13'
        classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$nav_version"
```

and in **app module** build.gradle:

```
   implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:$nav_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:$nav_version"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-testing:$nav_version"
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I can not believe that the build is working again! Tried a lot of solutions, and none worked. I just want to update my android project from java 8 to java 11, and it's just not building ... Thank you!

Comment: This worked for me as well. `2.3.1` -> `2.4.2`

Answer (score 5):

It will be solved, when 4.2.0 is stable.

[From the existing issue:](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/159542337)

> Android Gradle Plugin deprecated the getApplicationIdTextResource()
> API on the class BaseVariant in version 4.1.0 (see bug). The
> replacement API (onVariantProperties) did not work properly for
> feature libraries, so to avoid the deprecation warning, reflection was
> used. That is only a short term solution, and when AGP 4.2.0 is stable
> we should update to that version and remove the reflection immediately

So if you need Safe Args and do not need latest features of Gradle, keep Gradle version in Android Gradle Plugin version at 3.6.4. Once stable 4.2.0 released, update to the latest.

Comment: updated with 4.2.0 warning fixed

Answer (score 3):

This error happened after i updated kotlin version to 1.7.
this was for NavigationComponent in Android Studio

So I changed the nav_version to this and My issue was solved : "2.4.0-beta02"

```
// Navigation Component
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.4.0-beta02"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.4.0-beta02"
```

Answer (score 2):

For me it was because of different Kotlin versions between IDE Kotlin plugin and project_name/build.gradle file

`classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.72"`

> "Kotlin version that is used for building with Gradle (1.3.72) differs from the one bundled into the IDE plugin (1.4.31) "

**Once I made it even it started to compile again.**

Answer (score 2):

In my case I was using 2.3.1 version of navigation-fragment.
I just updated it to 2.4.2 and it's helped me

Answer (score 1):

So, What i have done is that I have upgraded all the gradle plugins as well as dependecies versions and then run, It worked for me

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and it was solved like this:
So I go to -> build.gradle file

My dependencies before upgrade

check the dependencies

I update Google services dependencies to latest version

```
dependencies {
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:(latest version)'
 classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:(latest version)'

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Android Studio 4.1** giving the following information and It will be removed in version 5.0 of Android Gradle Plugin.

> API 'BaseVariant.getApplicationIdTextResource' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'VariantProperties.applicationId'.
> It will be removed in version 5.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
> For more information, see TBD.
> To determine what is calling BaseVariant.getApplicationIdTextResource, use -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display more information.

Answer (score 0):

As @ianhanniballake has pointed out, it seems likely that it's caused by the Navigation Safe Args plugin, see the [existing issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/159542337), also referenced from his answer.  The issue was marked as fixed on 9 November.

In terms of fixing the build error, upgrading Android Studio from `4.1.0` to `4.1.1` fixed it for me.

Comment: Upgrading to 4.1.1 didin't fix the issue for me.

Comment: @ShadeToD I don't see it as a build error any more, just as a warning, as outlined in the existing issue in the tracker.  Are you still seeing it as an error?

Comment: upgrading to 4.2.0 did fix it.

Answer (score 0):

delete the .idea and .gradle files from the project .. it worked with me