# API 'BaseVariant.getApplicationIdTextResource' is obsolete

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

Android Studio is spitting this warning from Gradle as soon as I build my project:

```
API 'BaseVariant.getApplicationIdTextResource' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'VariantProperties.applicationId'.
It will be removed in version 5.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
For more information, see TBD.
To determine what is calling BaseVariant.getApplicationIdTextResource, use - 
Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display more information.
```

I've read that there is an open issue within [Google's Issue Tracker here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/159542337) which has been open for a few months but I would love to get a straight answer or at least a hint on how to run that line of code mentioned at the end of the warning:

```
To determine what is calling BaseVariant.getApplicationIdTextResource, use - 
Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display more information.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [API 'BaseVariant.getApplicationIdTextResource' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'VariantProperties.applicationId'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62156368/api-basevariant-getapplicationidtextresource-is-obsolete-and-has-been-replaced)

Comment: Not quite, this question only leads me to the same Google issue I included as part of my question.

Comment: looks like we will have to wait until version 4.2 is stable or something (https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/172824579)